# Github files changed is more than the files pushed fron the local repo

Tags: git, github

I checkout from staging branch to a new branch and I only  worked on a single file in that new branch ,I ran git status to check for a modified files and I have just one and I staged it and I commit it and push it to the remote repo,When I created a PR I found out that the file changed has more than a file,And I actually changed a file,I could not figure out why.

Comment: All I get from your question is that you changed a file, and a file is changed, and somehow that's not what you expected. But that's what you *should* expect based on what you said! So there's something missing here. See [ask].

Comment: If your PR features more than one file when you think you've only modified one, it might be that (non-exhaustive list) 1) you unadvertantly *did* modify (and add) other files, or 2) you did not create the branch from where you think you did, thus bringing other commits, or maybe even 3) you have hooks running which could have added something else into your commit.